# Importing working MariaDB innodb dump into new database and receiving Error 1071 Key too long

Tags: mariadb, import

Old server is MariaDB 10.6
New server is MariaDB 10.3

I mysqldump the old DB which is still the master copy and functioning.

[I made sure the new server DB is set to InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746207/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes) (like the old one) using this in the cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
```

Then with a fresh new maria DB (10.3 mind you), I do:

1. Log in and create database newdatabase
2. sudo  mysql -u root -p newdatabase < media_data_master.dump

The result is:

```
ERROR 1071 (42000) at line 266: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
```

The stackoverflow post I linked above talks about VARCHARs being all 255 and that causing the issue. Big problem however is that I don't know how I would ever fix that. The people who use the database are not even in my department, I'm just trying to move the thing to a new server.

I had also tried `create database my_db character set utf8 collate utf8_bin;` before I did the import but same problem.

If the old DB is still functional AND our replica appears to still be replicating perfectly, is there something I'm missing here that will allow me to import the dump and avoid this error?

Comment: For what reason do you not want to install the same version of MariaDB?

Comment: @mustaccio The problem was that we couldn't get 10.6 installed from the particular distro repositories. Its a stupid problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a significant downgrade.  This problem may not be the only one.

Anyway, see the following for 5 ways of addressing what I *susupect* it the problem: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

On the other hand, "1000" is a better clue.  You are using MyISAM.  Don't.  Instead, move to `ENGINE=InnoDB`.

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for any tables with that problem.

Search your my.cnf (on both servers) for "engine" to see if it is being forced.

Comment: Great thanks. I will figure out how to use innodb because I thought I was already.  ON the original DB, the only "engine" string I found was "#default_storage_engine=InnoDB". Same with the new one

Comment: I tried again from empty mysql directory, with "default_storage_engine=InnoDB" under [mysqld] and [mariadb] in the  /etc/my.cnf.d/mariadb-server.cnf    but its still 1000 bytes. Is the "1000 bytes" a definite and unmistakable indicator of myisam?

Comment: @postuple - 1000 shows up twice in that blog, both probably limited to MyISAM.  I don't know of such in InnoDB.  1000 columns per table?  If you can figure out which table is involved, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: :D how about this table with a varchar(4096)?? Should I tell the users that thats just not acceptable or is that a normal thing to do with this kind of database?  Thanks for the command, I found the issue right away

Comment: @postuple - `VARCHAR(marge max)` -- If the data allows, lower the max.  Else remove the `INDEX`.  Large max -- may as well be `TEXT`, which can't be indexed either.

Comment: Thanks, we are on the right path now. I'm not able to release more information but thanks a lot for getting me on the right path! Its an InnoDB but some DBAs are now finally looking at shortening the indexes larges than 1000 bytes